# Selecting which days of the week?

Tags: c#, wpf

Customer wants me to do "something" on specific days of the week that they can select via some kind of control. Is there something in WPF that can do this or something someone has already done that can achieve the same thing?

Currently I am looking at creating 7 check-boxes (one for each day) and allowing the customer to CHECK the boxes he wants (for the days in question) and then store them as INT values (0=Sunday, etc...) to be used when/where needed.

But before I do that, I was hoping there might be a more elegant solution already out there - any ideas? Or any proposals on how I could do it better then I have described above?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

**Simple solution:** 
I would recommend using the multi-select combobox: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/563862/Multi-Select-ComboBox-in-WPF

**Make your own:**
The great thing about wpf is that you can always style the multi select enabled ListView : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/64865/Enable-MultiSelect-in-WPF-ListView-2 to do what you want it to do. 
You would use DataTemplates for this purpose: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx

Answer (score 1):

why not simply use [listbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.aspx)? no need for anything external

just set selection mode to [extended](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.selectionmode.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this DevX search website](http://search.devexpress.com/)

It has a search panel with values 'All' | other check boxes.
What you can do is implement something similar by using a `WPF Expander` control after 'All' checkbox (instead of a Pipe character) which expands/collapses to display/hide other week days checkboxes and I think rest is self understandable.